# Run spring boot integration test using maven test but the embeded tomcat is not started

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I write an integration test for my spring boot application, it is shown as following code. It works fine in Eclipse IDE by run as Junit test and the embeded tomcat is started and shutdown automatically. But when I run it using maven install, it failed just because the embeded tomcat is not started. Should I need more configuration in Maven? How to do it?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestCoreConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class UserRegistrationTest {

@Autowired
private Receiver receiver;


@Test
public void shouldRegisterUser() {
    //Given
    String email = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-a-foo@bar.com";

    //When
    ResponseEntity<UserInfo> entity = registerUser(email);

    //Then
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, entity.getStatusCode());

    UserInfo registeredUser = entity.getBody();
    System.out.println ("The registered user ID is " + registeredUser.getUserId());

    String receivedMessages = receiver.getMessages().toString();
    assertTrue(receivedMessages + " expected to contain " + email,   receivedMessages.indexOf(email) != -1);
}

private ResponseEntity<UserInfo> registerUser(String email) {
    String password = "secret";
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(email, password);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/users/registration", userInfo,  UserInfo.class);
}
}
```

---

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.wangjun</groupId>
<artifactId>userRegistration-microservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>userRegistration-microservice</name>
<description>UserRegistration microservice</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.wangjun.microservices.userregistration.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
sshouldRegisterUser(com.wangjun.microservices.userregistration.rest.functional.UserRegistrationTest) Time elapsed: 1.031  sec  <<< ERROR! org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for     :Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpReq uest.java:78)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHtt pRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:551)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:512)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:363)
        at com.wangjun.microservices.userregistration.rest.functional.UserRegistrationTest.registerUser(UserRegistration Test.java:91)
        at com.wangjun.microservices.userregistration.rest.functional.UserRegistrationTest.shouldRegisterUser(UserRegistrationTest.java:37)
```

Comment: It looks like maybe Tomcat is not on the classpath at runtime with the maven tests. Any idea why? Did you give them any special treatment?

Comment: I copy the maven file here. I am a beginner for Spring boot. should I config the embeded tomcat server in the maven file? How to do it? I have not installed the tomcat in my machine. It seems not to config the tomcat if using gradle, any idea? thanks.

Comment: Looks OK. Maybe you have a port clash? Is anything running on the same port as your app (8080 by default)?

Comment: Recently blocked by something else, sorry for replying late. It should not a port clash. I have checked nothing is using 8080. When I firstly run "mvn spring-boot:run", and then run "mvn install", everything is fine and test cases can pass. It seems that I have to config maven for spring boot integration test?

Comment: What do you mean? How did you run the tests when it failed? (And no, there's nothing special about the maven config - it's just setting up te classpath.)

Comment: I've found my problem. It's ApplicationTests class in the test root folder. I forgot to add @IntegrationTest to this class. Finally I found this class is useless and delete it. It works fine right now using "mvn install/mvn test". Thank you very much. Spring boot is great!

Answer (score 10):

scan ports, set server port to a free one found

`@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")`

discover the port number

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port;
```

add port to url

```
restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:"+port+"/users/registration"...
```

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer. Worked perfectly for me. Thanks @Miodigy

Comment: Should be mark as correct answer. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Update for Spring 2.0.

My Tomcat was starting fine when running the app, but wasn't starting for me in my tests. @Miodigy's answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class TokenTest {
    @Autowired private SavedSearchesController controller
    @LocalServerPort private int port
```

Important points are:

`@SpringBootTest` - make sure to add the `webEnvironment` parameter.

`@LocalServerPort` - this is where spring will inject the random port.

Without `webEnvironment` Tomcat was not starting for me in my tests.